# Erro na configuração do RouterProvider do AngularJS

Tags: html5, angularjs, front-end, angularjs-directives

Importei o angular-route.js e fiz a seguinte configuração :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   angular.module("layoutxepa",["ngRoute"]);

   angular.module("layoutxepa").config(function (serialGeneratorProvider) {
     serialGeneratorProvider.setLength(5);
   });

   angular.module("layoutxepa").config(function ($routeProvider) {

   });

 </script>
```

**Segue o Erro**

```
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module  layoutxepa due to:
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: serialGeneratorProvider
```

Comment: `serialGeneratorProvider` não está definido. Cheque se o arquivo responsável por sua configuração está sendo carregado, e se o serviço está sendo adicionado à inicialização do Angular.

Comment: @OnoSendai o arquivo serialgenerator.js não estava sendo importado . obg pelo retorno

Comment: Sempre um prazer - fico feliz que a dica tenha solucionado seu problema!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema era que o arquivo

> serialGenerator.js

não estava sendo importado.

```
<script src="src/main/webapp/app-content/js/serialGenerator.js"></script>
```